# select column values based on max date and closest date

Tags: r, date, compare

I have a dataset as follows

```
Id    BMI    Date        Case   CaseDate 
1331  28.2   2012-05-15  No     NA
1331  26.4   2011-04-06  No     NA
1331  29.37  2014-04-01  No     NA
5074  30.02  2009-10-23  Yes    2014-08-06
5074  25.12  2011-07-15  Yes    2014-08-06
```

What I am trying to do is as follows

1) For Id where `Case=No`, Chose BMI that is closest to current date `(Sys.Date ())` and store this value in a new column (`New_BMI`)

2) For Id where `Case=Yes`, Chose BMI that is closest to date in the `CaseDate` column and store this value in new column (`New_BMI`)

The final output should look like this below.

```
Id    BMI    Date        Case   CaseDate     New_BMI
1331  28.2   2012-05-15  No     NA           29.37
1331  26.4   2011-04-06  No     NA           29.37
1331  29.37  2014-04-01  No     NA           29.37
5074  30.02  2009-10-23  Yes    2014-08-06   25.12
5074  25.12  2011-07-15  Yes    2014-08-06   25.12
```

The value of `New_BMI` for Id 1331 is 29.37 because this was the value closest to current date. The values of `New_BMI` for Id 5074 is 25.12 because this was the value closest to `CaseDate` (2014-08-06).

Any help on how to compute this `New_BMI` is much appreciated folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First be sure that you have Date class objects.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
df$CaseDate <- as.Date(df$CaseDate)
```

Then with dplyr, one way is group by Id And test for the conditions. The main function call is `BMI[which.min(Sys.Date() - Date)]`. This subsets the BMI column by the minimum length between the current date and the `Date` column. The same is done for `CaseDate`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  mutate(New_BMI = ifelse(Case == "No", BMI[which.min(Sys.Date() - Date)], 
                                        BMI[which.min(CaseDate - Date)]))
# Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
# Groups: Id [2]
# 
#      Id   BMI       Date   Case   CaseDate New_BMI
#   (int) (dbl)     (date) (fctr)     (date)   (dbl)
# 1  1331 28.20 2012-05-15     No       <NA>   29.37
# 2  1331 26.40 2011-04-06     No       <NA>   29.37
# 3  1331 29.37 2014-04-01     No       <NA>   29.37
# 4  5074 30.02 2009-10-23    Yes 2014-08-06   25.12
# 5  5074 25.12 2011-07-15    Yes 2014-08-06   25.12
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(1331L, 1331L, 1331L, 5074L, 5074L), BMI = c(28.2, 
26.4, 29.37, 30.02, 25.12), Date = structure(c(4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 
3L), .Label = c("2009-10-23", "2011-04-06", "2011-07-15", "2012-05-15", 
"2014-04-01"), class = "factor"), Case = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), CaseDate = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2014-08-06", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Id", 
"BMI", "Date", "Case", "CaseDate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I changed the second criteria to `BMI[which.max(CaseDate - Date)]` and it worked perfect